# Liquibase Groovy-DSL Spring

Tags: java, spring, groovy, liquibase, spring-shell

I am developing a `spring-shell` database migration tool.

At the moment i try to use liquibase with the [groovy-dsl extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-groovy-dsl).
My build.gradle includes the extension jar, also i declared liquibase in the `spring-shell-plugin.xml`

**spring-shell-plugin.xml**

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase" depends-on="postgresService">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="psqlDataSource"/>
    <property name="changeLog" value="com.example.db.DbChangelog_master"/>
    <property name="defaultSchema" value="${postgres.schema}"/>
</bean>
```

But everytime i start the application liquibase throws the following error

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports com.example.db.DbChangelog_master
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getParser(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:70)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:226)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 13 more
```

The documentation is a bit rare, also the jar is included in the classpath.

Does the groovy scripts need to be in `src/main/resources`? Currently they are in a seperate package in `src/main/groovy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your property

```
<property name="changeLog" value="com.example.db.DbChangelog_master"/>
```

is incorrect. This should be the path to your changelog file. If that file is a groovy file, it might be

```
<property name="changeLog" value="DbChangelog_master.groovy"/>
```

if that file is available on the classpath.

Comment: yh thought about it too. Concentrated  too much on other things, i will give this a try tomorrow thx in advance :)

Comment: coudln't reference the class, needed to reference the path to the groovy script